# Synchronization simplification

Tags: java

I'm currently working on threading and synchronization.
I'm trying to print "A" 2 times, "B" 1 time, and "C" 4 times with this program, which basically works but I was wondering if there is a smaller and simpler solution to this, like putting all the classes into one or something similar.

Here is the code.

```
public class foo {

public static int countA = 0;
public static int countB = 0;
public static int countC = 0;


public static void main(String[] args) {


    AThread athread = new AThread(new AClass());
    BThread bthread = new BThread(new BClass());
    CThread cthread = new CThread(new CClass());

    athread.start();
    bthread.start();
    cthread.start();


}

static class AClass {

    public synchronized void printA() throws InterruptedException {
        if(countA == 2)
            wait();
        for(int i=1; i<3; i++) {
            System.out.println("A"+i);
            countA++;
        }
    }

}

static class BClass{
    public synchronized void printB() throws InterruptedException {
        if(countB == 1)
            wait();
        for(int i=1; i<2; i++) {
            System.out.println("B"+i);
            countB++;
        }
    }
}

static class CClass{ 
    public synchronized void printC() throws InterruptedException {
        if(countC == 4)
            wait();
        for(int i=1; i<5; i++) {
            System.out.println("C"+i);
            countC++;
        }
    }
}

static class AThread extends Thread {

    AClass A = new AClass();

    AThread(AClass a){
        this.A = a;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            A.printA();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
static class BThread extends Thread {

        BClass B = new BClass();

        BThread(BClass b){
            this.B = b;
        }
        public void run() {
            try {
                B.printB();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
static class CThread extends Thread {

    CClass C = new CClass();

    CThread(CClass c){
        this.C = c;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            C.printC();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: *which basically works* I doubt that because since there is no synchronization between AClass and BClass and CClass  at all.

Comment: Why do you need threads? From the code snippet it seems each thread uses its own set of variables. I don't see anything common for all threads. So even it is working doesn't seem to need threads

Comment: There's a lot of useless boilerplate, disrespected naming conventions, useless calls to wait(), useless synchronized keywords. What is this code supposed to do? Basically every thread tutorial explains that you should not extend Thread, but pass a Runnable to a Thread. Why are you disrespecting that?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the task does not require threads, here is a different way of writing the code in the description using java 8 [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            System.out.println("A" + (i + 1));
        }
    }).thenRunAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("B1");
    }).thenRunAsync(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("C" + (i + 1));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As the first comment says, there is no synchronization at all going on between any of your objects.  Perhaps this might become apparent by changing the order in which you start the threads (C first, then B, then A).

For scheduling between Threads to work, you need to :

- find an object that is visible to both threads so that both can wait() and notify() on that object.
- establish the condition that will cause the waiting to stop and put that in a while()

so you get sort of :

`while (countA < 2) AClass.class.wait();`

***in the B thread*** (and catch the InterruptedException in the loop, don't propagate)

and in the A thread you put

`AClass.class.notify();`

after the print loop has exited.

You can (and in industrial settings mostly should) replace AClass.class with a synchronisation object dedicated to the purpose (and which has been made visible to both threads).

The while() is necessary because of what is known as "spurious wakeups" : a wait() will exit if a notify() has caused it to do so, but it can also exit without such a notify() having been issued.

And finally, note that the condition in the while() loop accesses countA field from thread B, while thread A might be updating it.  With simple integers this may still be failproof, but with more complex evaluations this is in itself a potential source of race condition errors so those accesses need to be synchronized in turn.  Also note that `while(countA<2)` might never become true if thread A crashes for whatever reason so this is ***not*** the most robust way of setting things up as it will cause system hangs.

If all this is more like gibberish than English, you should first try and find a decent tutorial on threading and study that carefully.